# Nativescript - Repeater with nested data

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have some data from external API.
It returns nested array, wchich looks like follows:

```
var myData = [
    {
        "id": 30,
        "type": "Product",
        "name": "Product Name",
        "children": {
            "661031278126991": {
                "id": 45,
                "type": "Releases",
                "name": "2019",
                "parent": 30,
                "children": {
                    "6611311403631192": {
                        "id": 12,
                        "type": "Features",
                        "name": "Clients",
                        "parent": 80,
                        "children": {
                            "66103580432771": {
                                "id": 80,
                                "type": "Tasks",
                                "name": "List",
                                "parent": 12
                            },
                            "66103144161527": {
                                "id": 45,
                                "type": "Tasks",
                                "name": "List B",
                                "parent": 12
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

The problem is that i have multiple "Tasks" for example and now i'm stuck.
I don't even know if it's possible to create a view from this data.

Below, i pasted some XML code that will surely not work, but it will help to explain what kind of layout i want to render. I just have hope that Repeater can render this somehow. Thank you for any advice.

```
<Repeater items="{{ myData }}">
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout class="sep">
                                <Label text="{{ type }}" class="item"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout class="sep">
                                <Label text="{{ children.name }}" class="item"></Label>
                                <StackLayout class="sep">
                                    <Label text="{{ children.children.name }}" class="item"></Label>
                                    <StackLayout class="sep">
                                        <Label text="{{ children.children.children.name }}" ></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                </Repeater>
```

Comment: listview would be better choice here.

Comment: I think this would cause an exception on android (and maybe on ios) because there are a lot of nested layouts here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I'm aware of this, but for now i have only @Manoj solution, and i'm unable to find any better.

Answer (score 1):

`Repeater` does not work with object, so you will have to loop through your `children` object and convert the key value pairs into an Array.

Then you will have to build a custom component that includes itself within a Repeater, so all your child elements can be rendered one after another.

**Parent Component**

```
<ScrollView>
  <Repeater items="{{ myData }}">
   <Repeater.itemTemplate>
     <comps:child-component></comps:child-component>
   </Repeater.itemTemplate>
 </Repeater>
```

**Child Component**

```
<StackLayout xmlns:comps="components">
    <Label text="{{ name }}" class="m-y-10 m-x-10 h3"></Label>
    <Repeater items="{{ children }}">
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <comps:child-component></comps:child-component>
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=61HtxT&v=3).

**Note:** If you are planning to render 100s of this type of array, then you must consider following a different approach to avoid performance hit. May be you can use a ListView to load first level of items, upon tap load the second level of items in the next screen.

Comment: Thank you @Manoj. I will test this deeply, some fast test shows that it's working.